# wget on Windows replaces path characters in --directory-prefix

Tags: wget

I'm trying to download a directory and all its subdirectories from a website, using *wget*.
Reading all other SO questions I arrived at this:

```
wget -nH --recursive --no-parent --cut-dirs=5 --reject "index.html*" --directory-prefix="c:\temp" http://blahblah.com/directory/
```

However, no mather how I try to formulate the `c:\temp`, *wget* always creates "@5Ctemp" in the current directory and does the download in that directory. I check the documentation but to no avail.
Preferably I would also be able to use an environment variable as `--directory-prefix`, eg

```
--directory-prefix=%PREFIX%
```

Comment: This is absolutely working on my end. Do you run that from `cmd` or `powershell`? From within a script or not? If anyone wants to verify, you can use `http://mirror.netcologne.de/apache.org/accumulo/` as a test URL.

Comment: I have tried from all of those :) (cmd, powershell, script, ...) Maybe it has something to do with the wget build. I seem to remember I couldn't download it from sourceforge (blocked at work), and found a build somewhere else.

Comment: Well possible... For reference: I tested using `GNU Wget 1.14 built on mingw32` - can't remember where I got it from, though :(

Comment: Then try version 1.14 from [here](https://osspack32.googlecode.com/files/wget-1.14.exe). The file is identical to the one I'm using.

Comment: Glad to have helped - I'll write a quick answer for this question, following [this line of thought](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251597/question-with-no-answers-but-issue-solved-in-the-comments)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the version of `wget` you're using (1.8.2) is either buggy or too old. It definitely works with newer versions, get one here:

- [`wget 1.11.4`](http://downloads.sourceforge.net/gnuwin32/wget-1.11.4-1-bin.zip) from [gnuwin32](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/)
- [`wget 1.14`](https://osspack32.googlecode.com/files/wget-1.14.exe) from [osspack32](https://code.google.com/p/osspack32/)
- [`wget 1.15`](http://eternallybored.org/misc/wget/wget-1.15-win32.zip) from [eternallybored.org](http://eternallybored.org/misc/wget/)

For completeness, here's a link to the [`wget` wiki download section](http://wget.addictivecode.org/FrequentlyAskedQuestions?action=show&redirect=Faq#download).